# want to concat the directory and file name

Tags: python, path

```
from pathlib import Path
destination_file = "foo.txt"
current_dir = Path.cwd()
out_file = current_dir + destination_file
```

Throws the below error
out_file = current_dir + destination_file
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'

Comment: Use `current_dir / destination_file`

Comment: use os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.curdir), 'destination.txt'))

Comment: @DaveAnkin - `pathlib` is meant to replace the `os.path.xxx` functions.

Comment: Make sure you write working examples. We have to guess whether this is `pathlib` and whether `destination_file` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

you recieving a Path object that cannot be concatenated to a string, instead do :

```
current_dir = Path.cwd() # WindowsPath('C:/full/path')
out_file  = current_dir.joinpath(destination_file) # WindowsPath('C:/full/path/dest_file.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks Adir so much.<error> The outfile path is C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\PycharmProjects\SLU_DailyReport_Automation\Daily_report_23_Dec_2020.xlsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\PycharmProjects\SLU_DailyReport_Automation\Testing.py", line 208, in <module>
    refresh_excel_app()
  File "C:\Users\prasannakumaravel\PycharmProjects\SLU_DailyReport_Automation\Testing.py", line 199, in refresh_excel_app
    wb_7 = xlapp.workbooks.open(out_file)
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in open
TypeError: must be real number, not WindowsPath</error>

Comment: The error is in a different place and a different issue, if you want you can open another question for it.. if the answer solved your issue please font forget to accept it